# What's an efficient process for passing PHP arrays to to populate multiple ChartJS graphs?

Tags: javascript, php, module, chart.js

I'm working on a new dashboard for a large PHP application to display different report from our systems modules in HTML tables as well as Charts/Graphs on a single page.

I currently have 6 HTML tables that I populated via queries to our databases. I'm wanting to take the PHP arrays and generate ChartJS graphs efficiently without having to create a bunch of files for every graph/array.

I'm obviously still in the early stages of setting up this functionality, but there will be over 100 different reports implemented for our various users and 5-10 reports on any of their dashboards.

Our system is already boggy. What's an efficient/logical way I can pass these PHP arrays to ChartJS without drastically adding to the performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

Just send the arrays to the browser using

```
echo json_encode( $data );
```

You would probably want to store that in a hidden field somewhere. After the page is loaded kick off the JS to actually load the charts. I am not very familiar with PhP or ChartJS but this seems like the standard way to pass data from the server to the browser. If I missed the mark and didn't answer your question feel free to ask a follow up and ill do my best to help out.

Comment: Idk that having 100+ hidden fields is the best way to go about it

Comment: @Habit the only other option is to store it in an array all in memory, I personally feel like that would be harder on the browser. With hidden fields the browser doesn't have to render anything and it just stored in the DOM. Also you stated that each user will only have 5 -10 reports on their dashboard so it should only be 5 - 10 hidden fields per dashboard, you really shouldn't render data you don't need on every request.